# How can I return a specific axis from an axes object by specifying the row and column?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, figure, axes

I've been learning Python on Jupyter Notebook for quite some while with the assignments of my tutors. This week I need to implement a function that does the following:

*Implement the function **selected_axis** so that the following plots are drawn with the function plot_subplots.
Look at the **plot_subplots** function to understand what your function receives as parameters and what the expected return values are.*

I've got the following libraries loaded:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

Here i get the **plot_subplots** function:

```
def plot_subplots(data, nb_rows, nb_cols, row, col):

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nb_rows, nb_cols, sharex=True, sharey=True)

    axis = selected_axis(axes, row, col, nb_rows, nb_cols)
    axis.plot(data)

    plt.show()

# Plot a linear function in a 3x3 matrix at position 1,2
plot_subplots(np.arange(1, 9), 3, 3, 1, 2)
```

The comment shows how the function would work, and which variables it receives. So I went on and implemented my function **selected_axis**:

```
def selected_axis(axes, row, col, nb_rows, nb_cols): 
    a = []
    if row <= nb_rows and col <= nb_cols:
        for column_id, rows in enumerate(axes):
            if column_id == col - 1:
                a.append(col-1)
        for row_id, row_value in enumerate(rows):
            if row_id == row - 1:
                a.append(row-1)

    axis = axes[a[1], a[0]] 
    return axis
```

If i run `plot_subplots(np.arange(1, 9), 3, 3, 1, 2)`, the following output is given, which seems to be consistent with what i was asked to achieve, namely plotting in the desired subplot:

[Output of `plot_subplots(np.arange(1, 9), 3, 3, 1, 2)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tcGp.png)

Now, I am confronted with the following test cell my tutors implemented:

```
# Test cell.
from unittest import TestCase

__ = TestCase()

_data, _rows, _cols, _row, _col = np.arange(1, 9), 3, 3, 1, 2
_fig, _axes = plt.subplots(_rows, _cols, sharex=True, sharey=True)
_ax = selected_axis(_axes, _row, _col, _rows, _cols)

__.assertTrue(_ax.get_subplotspec().colspan.start == _col and _ax.get_subplotspec().rowspan.start == _row,
              msg="Your function does not select the correct axis.")
_ax.plot(_data)
plt.show()

_data, _rows, _cols, _row, _col = np.arange(1, 9), 2, 5, 1, 4
_fig, _axes = plt.subplots(_rows, _cols, sharex=True, sharey=True)
_ax = selected_axis(_axes, _row, _col, _rows, _cols)

__.assertTrue(_ax.get_subplotspec().colspan.start == _col and _ax.get_subplotspec().rowspan.start == _row,
              msg="Your function does not select the correct axis.")
_ax.plot(_data)
plt.show()

_fig, _axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
selected_axis(_axes, 0, 0, 2, 2).plot(np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1) ** 2)
selected_axis(_axes, 0, 1, 2, 2).plot(-np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1) ** 2)
selected_axis(_axes, 1, 0, 2, 2).plot(np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1) ** 3)
selected_axis(_axes, 1, 1, 2, 2).plot(-np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1) ** 3)

__.assertTrue(_ax.get_subplotspec().colspan.start == _col and _ax.get_subplotspec().rowspan.start == _row,
              msg="Your function does not select the correct axis.")
_ax.plot(_data)
plt.show()

__.assertRaises(ValueError, selected_axis, _axes, 1000, 312, _rows, _cols)

print("\n\033[37;42;2m  Success! Your code works as intended.  \033[0m\n")
```

When executing it, I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-fb042c0cacf0> in <module>
      8 _ax = selected_axis(_axes, _row, _col, _rows, _cols)
      9 
---> 10 __.assertTrue(_ax.get_subplotspec().colspan.start == _col and _ax.get_subplotspec().rowspan.start == _row,
     11               msg="Your function does not select the correct axis.")
     12 _ax.plot(_data)

~\anaconda3\lib\unittest\case.py in assertTrue(self, expr, msg)
    763         if not expr:
    764             msg = self._formatMessage(msg, "%s is not true" % safe_repr(expr))
--> 765             raise self.failureException(msg)
    766 
    767     def _formatMessage(self, msg, standardMsg):

AssertionError: False is not true : Your function does not select the correct axis.
```

**As of now, I am completely clueless as to why the test cell is not giving me the expected results..**

I would be extremely grateful, if someone could help me!

Comment: That error is from the test cases, not python, saying you've plotted in the wrong subplot. Your output shows a line in row 0 column 1, but the instructions appear to ask you to plot in row 1 column 2 (assuming the instructions, like python, are 0-indexed)

Comment: @G.Anderson Thank you for your response! I took out the ```-1``` in every ```.append()``` statement and now i am confronted with ```IndexError: list index out of range``` for ```---> 17 _ax = selected_axis(_axes, _row, _col, _rows, _cols)``` i will update as soon as i have new insights on that error!

Comment: It's better to just flatten `axes` with `axes = axes.flatten()`, then you'll have flat array to index, which is much easier.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thanks! I'll try that and see what i can do about it!

Comment: ***UPDATE***: Got it to work, essentially i could get a workaround with my code, i did not add anything new, just restated it! The problem really was confusing the columns and rows in the ```for``` loops. I needed to understand what axes objects really are, this really helped me understand my issue. Thank you @G.Anderson and @TrentonMcKinney for your help! It is highly appreciated!